# Convert HH:mm to UTC date time in JavaScript using date-fns

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-fns

I'm working on an appointment booking React app where a teacher can set their virtual office hours in the form of a time slot.

```
let availability = ["09:00", "17:00"]; // from 9 AM to 5 PM local time
```

Since this time is local to the teacher, I'd like to store it as UTC time in the ISO 8601 format so that if a student is in a different region, I can parse it on the client and show this time in their appropriate timezone.

I tried using the `parse` function from `date-fns@2.22.1` like this

```
parse('09:00', 'HH:mm', new Date()); // => Wed Jan 01 0020 00:00:00 GMT-0456 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

But, this didn't return the time in my timezone (Central Standard Time).

Is there a way to represent this local time slot in UTC?

Comment: [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is a time standard, not a format. You might be thinking of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution which was inspired by @Anas Abdullah Al. Here are two simple functions which will convert from both UTC and a user's local time.

```js
const format = window.dateFns.format;

const convertLocalToUTC = (localTime) => {
  if (!localTime) {
    throw new Error("Time can't be empty");
  }
  return new Date(`${new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10)} ${localTime}`)
    .toISOString()
    .slice(11, 16);
};

const convertUTCToLocal = (UTCTime) => {
  if (!UTCTime) {
    throw new Error("Time can't be empty");
  }
  const currentUTCDate = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  const inputUTCDateTime = `${currentUTCDate}T${UTCTime}:00.000Z`;
  return format(new Date(inputUTCDateTime), "HH:mm");
};

const UTCTime = "14:00";
const localTime = "09:00";

console.log(convertLocalToUTC(localTime)); // 14:00 UTC
console.log(convertUTCToLocal(UTCTime)); // 09:00 CST
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/2.0.0-alpha0/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your desired output

```js
const inputTime = "09:00";

const outputDate = new Date(new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10) + " " + inputTime).toUTCString();

console.log(outputDate);
```

Comment: This does work but doesn't use date-fns. I did manage to rework it into a function using ISO 8601 format. https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-ramanujan-yf76sz?file=/src/index.ts